# Support for Ubuntu applications in Elementary

Tags: appcenter, ubuntu, package-management, aptitude

I am confused about support for applications packaged for Ubuntu, whether distributed directly by Ununtu or in third-party repositories, in Elementary OS.

I have searched for LibreOffice and Firefox (though the latter is available in Ubuntu only as a snap, unless a further repository is added) in the AppCenter and found neither.

These applications being quite common and popular, it seems surprising that there is no direct path to installing them in Elementary. All around, it seems the offerings from the AppCenter, though they may be carefully curated, are rather limited.

What is the current attitude for Ubuntu packages being installed in a deployment of Elementary OS, and is any path available for installing them outside of the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Searching for flatpak apps from within AppCenter is enabled after installation of the first flatpak app.

As you want to install Firefox, go to it's [FlatHub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.mozilla.firefox) page and click the install button. After that, searching for LibreOffice will give results, straight from within AppCenter.

Comment: So Elementary does not want users to add any native packages from the Ubuntu repositories, only its own curated packages, from its Debian-style repositories, or Flatpak packages through Flathub?